# Trying to get property of non-object in wp-includes/capabilities.php

Tags: errors

Once a minute I get the following notice sequence in debug.log:

```
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1022
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1023
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1023
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1026
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1026
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1022
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1023
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1023
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1026
[23-Oct-2012 13:27:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1026
```

I disabled all plugins and selected the default Twenty Eleven theme, but still get it. How can I troubleshoot this? I'm using WordPress 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

You probably already figured this out, but I just had this issue and figured it out. Hopefully, if anyone runs into this problem, this may help.

My problem came from the Disqus Comment System plugin. Because I had used my Disqus user name to do some test comments on a dev site, when I linked my production site to the dev site, it created comments on test blog posts that didn't exist.

I had to go into the database and delete the comment rows that were attached to nonexistent post IDs, which fixed the problem for me.

Comment: +1, I used the plugin [Delete All Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-all-comments/)

Answer (score 2):

The actual "sequence" of notices is half of what you posted above (see the 2 second offset for one, and for another the repeating line numbers).

This notice is from the [`map_meta_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap) function which maps custom post type capabilities to the regular or primitive post related capabilities.

Here are [lines 1020 through 1028 of */wp-includes/capabilities.php* (as in 3.4.2)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1011):

```
$post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

if ( ! $post_type->map_meta_cap ) {
    $caps[] = $post_type->cap->$cap;
    // Prior to 3.1 we would re-call map_meta_cap here.
    if ( 'edit_post' == $cap )
        $cap = $post_type->cap->$cap;
    break;
}
```

So what is technically happening is that in the first line of the above, the `$post` global does have a `$post_type` property, but when that is fed to [`get_post_type_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) the function fails and does not return a post type object.
Hence you get one notice from 1022 (`$post_type->map_meta_cap`), two from 1023 (`$post_type->cap->$cap`) and two from 1026 (`$post_type->cap->$cap`).

At this point I have to disappoint you though. What exactly is calling `map_meta_cap()`, whether from the core or not, and why the post type slug in question appears not to be a valid registered post type - I have no idea or suggestion.

Comment: Thank Johannes. I included both sequences for completeness as they always seem to come in pairs with one minute in between. I got the idea to delete browser cache, cookies etc. and the notices stopped. But reenabling plugins and the custom theme I'm using made it come back. I'll try to isolate it.

Comment: ***"But reenabling plugins and the custom theme I'm using made it come back. I'll try to isolate it."*** That should tell you everything you need to know, eh? :) You've got an improperly-registered custom post type.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I got this problem and to solve it.

I just clean the database transient options.

I used the plugin [WP-Optmize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) to do this. Just remember to make a backup before install and run the plugin. I've been using this plugin a while and is very effective.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are not developer specific answers. This should really be no more than a comment

Answer (score -2):

You can try to execute your commands within ACTION (because wordpress is already loaded normally at that time).
like this:

```
ADD_ACTION('init','your_function');

function your_function(){
    YOUR CODES HEREEEEEEEEEEE............
}
```

Comment: Please post real answers with valid info, not crap that is misleading or incorrect. Better to do proper research before posting posting answers ;-)

Answer (score -3):

The warnings are because data are not consistence in wp_posts table in database.

in my case, i used an e-commerce plugin which generated some records on wp_posts table, then the plugin was disabled but the records were still in the table.

To find out which record, you can add a temporary var_dump on capabilities.php (don't forget to remove it after testing because it's a core file).

For example, to know which record caused the warning for line #1165 $post_type->map_meta_cap, insert the code as below:
if (!isset($post_type->map_meta_cap)) var_dump($post);

again, as pointed out, it's just warning.

hope it helps.